# ¿Cómo guardar un diccionario con saltos de línea en un archivo?

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo Python y no se mucho, por no decir nada, y mi duda es la siguiente tengo el siguiente código:

```
import json
d={}
with open ("prueba.txt","a") as f:
    d["Nombre"]="Sebastian"
    d["Edad"]=1000
    d["Numero"]= 2222
    t=json.dumps(d)
    f.write(t + '\n')
    f.close()
```

Y en archivo queda guardado así:

> {"Nombre": "Sebastian", "Edad": 1000, "Numero": 2222}

Y mi pregunta es si existe una forma de que en el archivo quede guardado asi:

```
{
    "Nombre": "Sebastian", 
    "Edad": 1000, 
    "Numero": 2222
}
```

Esto solo seria por mera estética y nada mas, y también para que si quiero ingresar mas datos no quede todo en una sola línea

Comment: Puede ser más conveniente utilizar un visualizador de JSON, por ejemplo los navegadores tienen extensiones, visual studio code también.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el parámetro [`indent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) para establecer los espacios de identación de cada clave, lo que automáticamente te agregará saltos de líneas:

```
import json
d={}

d["Nombre"]="Sebastian"
d["Edad"]=1000
d["Numero"]= 2222
print(json.dumps(d,indent=4))

{
    "Nombre": "Sebastian",
    "Edad": 1000,
    "Numero": 2222
}
```

Ahora una aclaración importante, un archivo `json` es una serialización de un objeto, en este caso un diccionario, como se vea el archivo no tiene ninguna importancia, por que lo importante es la estructura. Dado que JSON es un medio muy común para transmitir información es muy probable que un formato compacto sea incluso más deseable que un formato más legible.